# Rails: turn existing Paperclip attachments into Image class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, has-many

If I have lots of different kinds of Paperclip-attached images spread over several different models in a production environment, and I want to remove the attachments from those models and create an `Image` class that can have a relationship to those models, how can I do that?

Like, I can create the `Image` class and all, but how can I best translate the attribute-based solution into a relationship-based one so I don't lose existing images for specific records?

All advice welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it right in your migration.  Say users have an avatar:

```
class CreateImage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string 'url'
      t.integer 'user_id'
    end

    User.all.each do |user|
      Image.create(user: user, url: user.avatar)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Far out that's simple. Cheers!